# Wetting the surface for soaking Nylon fabric in metal

Tags: surface-tension, metals, wetting

I'm trying to create metal covered lace.
My sister would use it as an artistic material.

### An interesting material

A relevant point is that the mechanical rigidity of the metal is used, so it is not about plating the surface with a thin layer of metal.
Actually, the metal may be thick as long as it keeps some fabric structure visible.
Using the metal below, the material would be rigid, but brittle. It could be broken and reheated on the fracture line to change the shape.
Also, the metal can be melted in a larger area by a heat gun - keeping the fabric shape.

### Metal and polymer

The lace is usually made from a polyamide like Nylon, with melting points around 200°C.

The metal I have choosen is the eutectic alloy of bismuth and tin 58%Bi/42%Sn, melting at 138°C.

Already expected, dipping the fabric into the liquid metal at a temperature of about 150°C did not wett the surface of the polymer very good, so that it got surrounded by metal, but not soaked in it. The metal did not go between fibers.

As far as I understand, the only issue is that the metal needs to wet the fiber surface. Then it would soak by capilarry forces.

### How to make liquid metal wet poliamide fibers?

*There are some physics questions involved here, mostly on the metal side, and chemical questions on the polymer side. Let me know when you think something does not fit here.*

My ideas so far are that ideally, the surface tension of the metal would be reduced. But I am not expexting that to be possible.

A mechanical method of kneading fabric with metal may work partially - but then, it may drip off later ehen reheated.

On the chemical side, there are various ways to treat polymer surfaces for making surface coatings stick.
Is that even helpful - seeing that the metal does not touch the surface in the first place?

*(Based on your input, I'll create a related question for the chemistry site.)*

Comment: Do you need to use nylon? Have you tried polyester or blends?

Comment: Interesting point - the style of fabric to be used will need to be lace, but not a specific piece pr pattern. So I can try to find other materials - what would bleds mean? (Not sure, but there seem to be blends in other cases which have a melting point too low)

Comment: @LDC3 Yes, I will try polyester.

Comment: I believe there is a polyester/nylon blend (I'm not sure if they are melted together, or each is a separate strand in the fabric), or polyester/cotton (if you are careful, the cotton shouldn't burn). You might try linen (it can take a high temperature iron so it shouldn't be a problem).

Comment: @LDC3 Thanks, I was focussed on the metal part of the problem - I see it makes at least sense to test available variants on the fabric side (primer for glue on fabric was already tried, with not much effect)